# CSS - Background stops

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with 23 fields (columns across) and have this CSS for html and body:

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

my table is very long and has no styling to it and is not wrapped in a div, but the border-top and background stop as I scroll across to see the rest of the table, does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Here is a JFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jsuske/7g9qybjp/

Comment: Show your HTML. Maybe a Fiddle too>

Comment: Add the HTML markup that goes with that or even better create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that showcases your problem.

Comment: Maybe apply those styles to the table instead of the body? Body is kind of just a viewport and depending on what is being scrolled could mean the body is being left behind as you scroll across. I'd still suggest a jsfiddle so we can take a look :)

Comment: By the way.. what colour are you expecting? Because the `body` is white. so all you see is white. Is the HTML of your table valid?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsuske/7g9qybjp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/5ouvn063/1/

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family:"Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.table {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
}
```

Instead of applying `border-top: 10px solid black;` to the body you can apply it targeting the **.table class** of the table inside the iframe. You need to remember to add also a **white background** to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add style to your table in this way:

```
table {
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

And delete the next attributes related to body and html:

HTML: `background-color: #e2e2e2;`

BODY: `background-color: #fff;`
      `border-top: solid 10px #000;`

Comment: Sorry, someone downvote this post. Was not this the information you were asking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
table {
background-color: #fff;
border-top: solid 10px #000;
color: #333;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

The body tag is only the width of the view port unless otherwise specified. If you select body for this styling, it will only extend for as far as the window itself. You need to style that top border to the table itself.